# Installing abiword on amzon ec2 fails due to dependencies

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I am installing abiword-2.8.6 on amazon ec2 instance

But it failing due to dependencies

```
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonoboui-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgsf-1.so.114
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonobo-2.so.0
Error: Package: wv-1.2.4-4.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgsf-1.so.114
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libfribidi.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgsf-gnome-1.so.114
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libORBit-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libglade-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libtermcap.so.2
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeui-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgconf-2.so.4
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgconf-2.so.4
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeui-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeprint-2-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libfribidi.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomeprintui-2-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgsf-gnome-1.so.114
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomevfs-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonobo-activation.so.4
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomevfs-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libORBit-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libglade-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonoboui-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonobo-2.so.0
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libbonobo-activation.so.4
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgsf-1.so.114
Error: Package: 1:abiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-keyring.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-keyring.so.0
Error: Package: 1:libabiword-2.6.4-8.el5.2.i386 (epel)
           Requires: librsvg-2.so.2
```

Can anyone tell me do i need to resolve dependencies one by one .. or is there any alternate method to install with dependencies..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are installing via rpm.. First install EPEL

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse

Then you can run

```
yum install abiword
```

That will install it an all requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. I am installing through yum  and I have added epel to my yum also

Comment: run the following command: cat /etc/*release*

Comment: I launched new instance .. abiword installed without any problem.. thanks